# Java extract strings/tags?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have sets of strings that look like this:

```
[{"tag":"rat","score":0.7973},{"tag":"lion","score":0.7184},{"tag":"dog","score":0.2396},{"tag":"woof","score":0.1944},{"tag":"cat","score":0.1157}]
```

I would like to print the following in order from the string:

```
rat
lion
dog
woof
cat
```

How can i do this?

Comment: is what u show completely in a string?

Comment: Try to use org.json library.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use regex to parse JSON. Use a library.

Comment: JSON does not guarantee order.

Comment: @SyamS it maintains the order. See my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper use any JSON parsing library such as [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and convert it into Java Object.

**Note:** It returns `java.util.LinkedHashMap` that maintains the order.

Sample code:

### GSON

```
String jsonString="[{\"tag\":\"rat\",\"score\":0.7973},{\"tag\":\"lion\",\"score\":0.7184},{\"tag\":\"dog\",\"score\":0.2396},{\"tag\":\"woof\",\"score\":0.1944},{\"tag\":\"cat\",\"score\":0.1157}]";
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
for (Map<String, String> map : data) {
    System.out.println(map.get("tag"));
}
```

### Jackson

```
String jsonString="[{\"tag\":\"rat\",\"score\":0.7973},{\"tag\":\"lion\",\"score\":0.7184},{\"tag\":\"dog\",\"score\":0.2396},{\"tag\":\"woof\",\"score\":0.1944},{\"tag\":\"cat\",\"score\":0.1157}]";
TypeReference<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
    for (Map<String, String> map : data) {
        System.out.println(map.get("tag"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("There might be some issue with the JSON string");
}
```

output:

```
rat
lion
dog
woof
cat
```

Comment: good solution for json but i'd prefer not to add another library

Comment: It's your choice. Finally you will come here again.

Comment: can you list the imports for the GSON? i'm not sure which "Type" import to use

Comment: It's `java.lang.reflect.Type`

Comment: I have included the json string as well. You can pass `Reader` as well to read the json string from file.

Answer (score 3):

```
    (?:.*?{"tag":)"(.*?)",.*?}
```

This will match all the required groups.See Demo

http://regex101.com/r/aN1bX5/1

Comment: Yeah sorry, took me a bit longer to find the error but still breaks on this: `{"tag":"test \"this\", oops!","score":0.7973}` and it assumes `"tag"` comes right after `{`

Comment: but that doesn't adhere to the format being asked here.That way there can be numerous possibilities.

Comment: Numerous possibilities that will all be matched by `"tag"\s*:\s*"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"` ;)

Comment: @vks how do i use the regex with java, i can't seem to be able to escape the quotes.                                                        `And console says: "Illegal repetition near index 5
(?:.*?{\"tag\":)\"(.*?)\",.*?}"`

Answer (score 3):

This string is JSON so you could use a JSON parser to do this.

If you're looking for an easy way to get all the values of `"tag"` use this regex and extract group 1 in Java.

```
"tag":"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/33moZzAiMnAAT3-h)

Double-escape this if you're gonna use it in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"tag\":\"((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"");
```

Comment: @funkwurm How on earth do i use this in java since there are quotes in the regex? I try escaping them and all i get is errors about pattern syntax.

Comment: You probably have to double-escape stuff because Java itself uses the `\` to escape both slashes and quotes. I'll add a java-line to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The match is in the first capture group

```
(?:"tag":"|\G(?!^))([^"]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use regex to parse JSON. Use a library like GSON or Jackson

```
JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < jsa.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json = jsa.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(json.getString("tag"));
}
```